# Setting file size on the file constructor

Tags: javascript, file, blob

Is there a way we could set the size property of the `File` object. I will be getting the size as number from the api.

This is what I tried,

```
const file = new File([''], filename , { size: 100 })
```

This does not seem like working. Can someone help?

Comment: You can't use size inside File constructor (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [File documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File)

```js
const file = new File([new ArrayBuffer(100)], 'test.txt')

console.log('The size of the file in bytes: ' + file.size + 'bytes')
```

Answer (score 0):

The size is determined by the data in the File object. It isn't an independent value that you can explicitly set.

Comment: is there a way we could still set it?

Comment: By putting data of that size in the file object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is your array buffer is empty so that you are getting 0 size. Also pass the second parameter as string for the filename.

```js
 const file = new File(['hello world!'], 'filename')
 console.log(`size of file = ${file.size}`)
```

As you are telling that you want to set the size of the file according to the received size then you have to put the data of that size in that file.

As the third parameter is for type and last modified.